# What are the motives of the aliens in the movie "Extraterrestrial"?

Tags: movie, character-motivation, extraterrestrial

Watching the movie *Extraterrestrial* leaves me with mixed feelings. It is visually and atmospheric appealing, with a bitter sweet cynical ending. I would not say it is not worth watching.

But what me bothered is this:

Do the actions of the aliens make any sense at all? Or are they just a chaining together of all the cliches about alien abductions that the producers put randomly in the movie?

Is there any background information what the motives of the aliens are?

e.g.:

- What except sadistic voyeurism would be an explanation to the anal probe scene?
- Why could the main character free herself so easily and all the others not?
- Why did the aliens send some people back and some not? (Especially if they act out of sadistic motives?)
- What role played the crashed UFO? The aliens where active (we see at the beginning of the movie) in the area before. And there is at least one intact UFO. To me the crash had no impact on the plot.

Comment: “What except sadistic voyeurism would be an explanation to the anal probe scene?” — Honestly, what’s wrong with a healthy curiosity about what’s up someone’s butt?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - Proctologists everywhere would disagree with him

Comment: I thought my answer to this one was about as convincing as you're going to get, featuring an interview with the filmmakers. Is there anything else you'd like to address before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filmmakers apparently relied quite heavily on the writings of UFOlogist David Jacobs when penning their original screenplay.

> **What research did you do for the film? Did you work with any UFO experts or read any books on it?**
>
> **Stuart:** ***There’s a book called Secret Life and its sequel called The Threat by David Jacobs, a professor from the United States.
> They’re about alien abduction. They’re very academic accounts.** He
> uses hypnosis – hypnotherapy – on people who claim they’ve been
> abducted by aliens. He has this whole process. The whole thing that’s
> controversial about hypnotherapy is people say, ‘you suggest things’
> or ‘you put ideas in their minds’, which can happen, but he’s very
> aware of that. He doesn’t lead people on; he just allows them to talk.
> The book is this bunch of transcripts describing people’s experiences.
> I think they were written in the late 1970s. When you start reading
> it’s quite funny, like ‘hahaha it’s a typical alien scenario, they
> come in my room, the aliens take me’. But you keep reading them, more
> and more accounts, and it gets weird because there’s so many
> similarities in what people describe; very weird, specific things.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Starburst Interview: THE VICIOUS BROTHERS | EXTRATERRESTRIAL](http://www.starburstmagazine.com/features/interviews/10095-the-vicious-brothers-interview)</sup></sub>

In his book [The Threat: Revealing the Secret Alien Agenda](https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Books/Threat-Revealing-Secret-Alien-Agenda-David-Jacobs/0684848139), Jacobs ascribes alien visitors with four primary motivations;

> *The Abduction Program.
>
> The Breeding Program.
>
> The Hybridization
> Program.*
>
> [With the ultimate goal being]
>
> **The Integration Program:** *The aliens prepare the abductees for future events. Eventually, the
> hybrids or the aliens themselves integrate into human society and
> assume control.*
>
> <sub><sup>[David Jacobs: The Threat - Chapter 12](https://www.bibliotecapleyades.net/vida_alien/thethread/thethread12.htm)</sup></sub>

Which goes some way to explaining why some abductees were released and others were not.

---

Note also that the filmmakers played with the idea (or at least the concept) that the alien's motivations might also be *sexualised*

> **Colin:** *Did they share the anal probes?*
>
> **Stuart:** *There was definitely some weird experiments, some weird shit –
> lurid sexual shit is like a common thing in real alien abductions.*
>
> **Q. Horny aliens?**
>
> **Colin:** *Yeah, fucking horny aliens!*
>
> **Stuart:** *They have a horny agenda! I think reading those books
> definitely makes you go ‘wow, you never know’.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Starburst Interview: THE VICIOUS BROTHERS | EXTRATERRESTRIAL](http://www.starburstmagazine.com/features/interviews/10095-the-vicious-brothers-interview)</sup></sub>